# How to Create Multi-Language Store in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I have a Magento store and I want to create a store for multiple languages.

can anyone gives briefly describe how to set up the store?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ekk4rd's answer is already great, but I just wanted to add that you also need to do some server configuration. You need to pass the website and store view IDs in the server configuration.
This is crucial in order for your stores to function properly.

Read more here:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/multi-site/ms_over.html

Answer (score 1):

You will need 1 Website => 1 Store Group => 2 Store Views.
In the storeviews you can change the locale in Admin Configuration.

For a detailed guide what do do you may want to refer to some guides. e.g. https://inchoo.net/magento-2/magento-2-administration/create-multi-language-store-magento-2-part-2/